# Rosh Hashanah as a Day of Friendliness

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Are there any texts or commentators which discuss the idea of Rosh Hashanah being a day of friendliness?

The Artscroll/Stone on Bamidbar 23:22 follows Rashi's understanding ([Bamidbar 23:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.23.21?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.23.21.5-24.1&lang2=he)) of "utru'at" as from the language of re'ut (though other meforshim stick with "trumpet blast"). If one can understand tru'ah here as neighborliness, this might add a dimension to the meaning of Rosh Hashanah as Yom T'ru'ah.

Is anyone familiar with sources which explore this possibility?

Comment: Regardless of if it's cited by the Meforshim, it's a cool Dvar Torah nonetheless.

Comment: Well, we're taught around here that you're not really supposed to talk on Rosh Hashana. Which kind of gets in the way of being friendly...

Comment: side note:yom kippur is called a day of friendliness,as stated in the machzor

Comment: @sam post here a link to a machzor stating that "yom kippur is called a day of friendliness",

Comment: @rosends which authority, OLDER than Rashi, concluded also that "tru'at" תרועת of Bamidbar 23:21 comes from "re'ut" רעות? (I am not able to tell from the answers below if the quoted authority is OLDER than Rashi.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is stated by the [B'nei Yissakhar](http://rabbishimon.com/tzadikim/showz.php?p=dinov.htm) ([Maamarei Hodesh Tishrei Maamar 3 - Yom Teruah Derush 3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14491#p=26&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=%25u05EA%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05E2%25u05D4)):

> וכן יש לפרש יום תרועה, לשון ריעות וחיבור, התחלת מעשה לקרב ולהגיש החיבור פנים בפנים, הוא יהיה לכם, הכל תלוי במעשיכם
>
> Similarly one can explain "a day of *teruah*", as an meaning 'friendliness' and 'connection', the beginning of the act to connect to God intimately, all based on one's actions.

This is part of a lengthy derush there.

Comment: I admit I was not 100% sure how t translate the passage, ayein sham...

Comment: Don't sweat it; that was a hard passage. +1

Comment: Really good! I wouldn't have thought of that common *shoresh*. The "friendliness" appears to be a logical connection from Rosh Hashannah to Yom Kippur as we are required to ask forgiveness from others and this action increases friendship.

Comment: @mevaqesh which authority, OLDER than Rashi, concluded also that "tru'at" תרועת of Bamidbar 23:21 comes from "re'ut" רעות? (Would it be correct that the authority you quoted in this answer is YOUNGER than Rashi?)

Answer (score 6):

[Yannai](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanai_(Payetan)) has a phrase in one of his kerovot for Rosh Hashanah (Zulai's ed., [p. 321](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39280&st=&pgnum=343)) that goes:

> וירצה בעם בו תרועת מלך

In N. Bronznick's book on Yannai's liturgy (Piyyutei Yannai - Biurim U'pirushim, pg. 388) the author is most certain that Yannai was hinting at this double entendre of "רעות"; friendship/closeness between God and His people.

In the posthumously printed Mishnas Sachir on Moadim ([p. 156](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53767&st=&pgnum=176&hilite=)), R. Teichtal also explores this similar idea where the Jewish people are united with one another *and* God, but takes this play-on-words further indicating that it alludes to "smashing" ("תרועם בשבט ברזל") revealing another element of the greatness of RH that it can destroy the enemies of the Jewish people.