# What other phrase did the rabbis use to describe "yom teruah" besides the ones below?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, talmud-gemara, commentaries, rosh-hashanah-new-year

What other phrase did the rabbis use to describe "yom teruah" besides the ones below?

Our rabbis of blessed memory gave additional "phrases" to describe or to name our holy days.

For example, the rabbis called Shabbat "the first of the holy days"; and Passover "time of our liberation"; and Sukkot "the season of our rejoicing", etc...

Besides "Rosh Hashanah" or "Yom Din" [http://thegemara.com/composing-rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-judgment/](https://thegemara.com/composing-rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-judgment/) or "Day of Friendliness" [Rosh Hashanah as a Day of Friendliness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85842/rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-friendliness/85846) what other phrase did the rabbis use to describe or to name "yom teruah" (Numbers 29:1) or "zikhron teruah" (Leviticus 23:24)?

Answer (score 3):

Yom Hazikaron. That's a pretty "obvious" one. It's all over the Siddur.

Comment: upvote. Even if "It's all over the Siddur", still give a reference or an example, with page number and/or .jpg upload. Please.